# How to show the browsed image immediately after browsing from system using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to show an image inside a table that is stored in a JavaScript variable. Below is my code and I don't know how to finish it. After clicking on submit, I want to show that image below the submit button.

```
<script type="text/ecmascript" language="javascript">
    function myname() {
        var image1 = document.getElementById("image").value;
        alert(image1);
        document.getElementById("abc").style.display = "block";
    }
</script>

<body style="text-align:center; margin-top:50px; width:50%;">

<form action=" " method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit="myname()">

    <fieldset style="text-align:center; height:200px; color:#0000FF;">

        <legend style="border: #0000CC 1px solid;"> Upload Image</legend>

        <table width="200" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="6px">
            <tr>
                <td height="20px;">Image</td>
                <br/>
                <td><input type="file" value="" name="image" id="image"/></td>
            </tr>
            <td id="abc"></td>
        </table>
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">

    </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: after submitting , get image path and put that path image tag below submit button it will be shown. ? or something else u want?

Comment: i dont want that image should insert into any folder because i have some other action(croping) after that a final image will stored in folder.plz help me

Comment: what about if you select image and without submit button it will show below submit button , selected image.?

Comment: yes you are right.I got it.Thankyou foryour suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this, may be you want like this... when you select image without submition it will be shown in submit button.

```js
function onFileLoad(e) {
    $('#show_selected_image').html('<img src="'+e.target.result +'"/>');
}

function displayPreview(files) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = onFileLoad;
    reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body style="text-align:center; margin-top:50px; width:50%;">

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit="myname()">

    <fieldset style="text-align:center; height:200px; color:#0000FF;">

        <legend style="border: #0000CC 1px solid;"> Upload Image</legend>

        <table width="200" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="6px">
            <tr>
                <td height="20px;">Image</td>
                <br/>
                <td>
                    <input type="file" name="image" id="image" onchange="displayPreview(this.files);"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <td id="abc"></td>
        </table>
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
        <br/>
        <div id="show_selected_image"></div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: @sradha check my answer is this helpfull for you?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to this,

```
document.getElementById("abc").innerHTML = "<img src=image1 />"
```

and i hope abc will be a container. i'm not sure you can chek this and post your reply

```
function myname(){
  var image = document.getElementById("image").value;
  doucment.getElementById("abc").style.display="block"; 
  document.getElementById("abc").innerHTML = "<img src =" + image + " />";
  }
```